# python error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new in python, I've coded below:

```
import warnings
import requests
from colorama import init
init(autoreset=True)

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


with open('ips.txt','r') as urls:
    for url in urls.readlines():
        req = url.strip()
        try:
            page=requests.get(req, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, stream=True, timeout=10)
            soup = BS(page.text)

            print('\033[32m' + req + ' - Title: ', soup.find('title').text)
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            print('[!] Timeout!')
```

Am trying to print the titles of links from IPs.txt

Output:
https://gyazo.com/fadb8f3427ecdeebb252779bd253a15c

I've got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_1.py", line 19, in <module>
    print('\033[32m' + req + ' - Title: ', soup.find('title').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

any how to solve this?

thank you
regards.

Answer (score 0):

If the soup does not have the `<title>` tag then `soup.find('title')` returns `None`. You must check the return value before attempting to use it:

```
title_tag = soup.find('title')
if title_tag:
    # Do something with title_tag.title
    # For example, extract the title as string title_tag.title.string
else: 
    # No title, do something else
```

Comment: it print <titlte>XXX</title> how to get rid of that and make it print just the "XXX". without <>Blah</>

Comment: It's a different question, but I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your `try..except` segment a straight forward way (to my mind) would be to use:

```
    try:
        page=requests.get(req, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, stream=True, timeout=10)
        soup = BS(page.text)
        print('\033[32m' + req + ' - Title: ', soup.find('title').text)
    except AttributeError:
        # do something...
```

Let me know if I am missing something here (never used **BS4**).

Answer (score -2):

Ok so I found the issue, when you put `.text` you forgot the parentheses so it should be `.text()`

Comment: It not callable, it will getting me error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_1.py", line 20, in <module>
    print('\033[32m' + req + ' - Title: ', soup.find('title').text())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`